# Solving $(\prod^t_{i=1} N_i m_i)!$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, factorial, integers, binomial-distribution

I would like to know how to solve or simplify the factorial $(\prod^t_{i=1} N_i m_i)!$.

Here, $i, N_i, m_i$ are positive integers.

**My effort:**

$$(\prod^t_{i=1} N_i m_i)!$$
$$\implies (\prod^t_{i=1} N_i m_i) (\prod^t_{i=1} N_i m_i - 1)!$$
$$\implies (\prod^t_{i=1} N_i m_i) (\prod^t_{i=1} N_i m_i - 1) (\prod^t_{i=1} N_i m_i - 2) \ldots 3.2.1$$

I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Hint: $$(ab)! = (a!)^{b}\prod_{k=1}^b \binom{ak}{a}.$$
I'm not exactly sure if it helps...

Comment: @ChrisTáfula, Thanks. The quantity I have given here is a product of more than $2$ variables. So, I need to figure out a quantity something like $(abc\ldots xyz)!$ .